# How do I make this php URL transition work?

Tags: php

Basically my task is,through the mandatory use of _GET,I'm supposed to make a code that fetches a specific php file when someone types in something like `..php?page=airlines` and I dunno if I'm just lacking information or what but this isn't working router.php:

```
<?php

$nav =array("home"=>"C:\xampp\htdocs\project\home.php",
    "flight"=>"C:xampp\htdocs\project\flight-detail.php",
    "order"=>"C:xampp\htdocs\project\order-flight.php,",
    "testimonial"=>"C:xampp\htdocs\project\add-testimonial.php");


if ( isset($nav[$_GET['page']]) )
{
  echo header('Location: ' . $nav[$_GET['page']]);
}
```

Comment: You're not really fetching them, are you?  You're using an HTTP redirect by passing a Location header, which is not going to work with a local file path.

Comment: Hi, please remember that 'this isn't working' is not enough evidence. You need to edit the question to include a description of exactly what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that `\f` in double quotes will become a linefeed. Backslashes must escape themselves / better yet use standard forward slashes for all paths. And yes, what you're looking for is likely `include` - not a redirect. As the question is currently presented, it cannot be answered precisely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass an array with php file directories into \_GET](//stackoverflow.com/q/53116219)

Comment: Change your file references to relative URL references - `/home.php` or `/flight-detail.php` and it should basically work.  Then you need to deal with edge cases and security - in addition to `isset()` check that it is `!empty()` as well, and then check if the value passed is a valid key in your array.  If all of those are true, *then* you can redirect.  If any of them are false, display an error message of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question, there are many ways to reach your goal.

I write an example that no change very your code:

```
<?php
$myPath="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\";
$nav =array("home"=>"home.php",
    "flight"=>"flight-detail.php",
    "order"=>"order-flight.php,",
    "testimonial"=>"add-testimonial.php");

if ( isset($_GET['page']) and !empty($_GET['page']))
{
  $myFile=nav[$_GET['page']];//i assume that in page there are only array keys value 
  echo header('Location: ' . myPath.$myFile);//i.e. I suppose  in page there is home output is: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\home.php"; file
}
else
{
  echo 'error: page not found!';
}
```

An other "easy" solution is to create in first page the link where the user can choose the page:

```
<a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\home.php">HOME<a>
<a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\flight-detail.php">FLIGHT DETAIL<a>
....
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's kind of funny I figured something quite similar around the time you replied ,thanks for a more detailed version though,I've never used anything like $myPath before , but I definetely see a variety of uses to it :)

Comment: :) $myPath is a variable that you can use and in future if you want to modify the content is more easy instead of to change all the rows where there is wrote the path...